# How can I add one component into another component using selector in angular?

Tags: angular, parent-child, selector

In angular, there is one feature available that we can create a component once and then reuse it anywhere in the project.

I am working on one complex project where lot's of components are available. and now I want to make all these components more reusable.

That's why, I want to reuse my layout in the following way :

```
<car-layout [color]="'red'">
  <steering [color]="'black'"></steering >
  <rear-view-mirror [size]= "'12'"></rear-view-mirror>
</car-layout>
```

But I don't know how can it work !
If anyone know about it then please guide me for this...

Comment: Search for "Angular Content Projection". It'll probably suffice your needs.

Comment: are you saying nothing shows up now?

Comment: @JohnPeters, I haven't try it yet, and I can't get any reference for this kind of structure, that's why I asked here. if anyone do this kind of stuff then they can guide me for that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to insert HTML elements or other components in a component, then you do that using the concept of content projection. In Angular, you achieve content projection using **< ng-content >< /ng-content >**.  You can make reusable components and scalable applications by properly using content projection.

lets create one component i.e. GreetComponent.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
     selector: 'greet',
     template: `<div class="container">
                 <ng-content> </ng-content>
             </div>`
 })
 export class GreetComponent{ }
```

AppComponent.ts

```
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
     selector: 'App',
     template: `<greet>
                    <h1>Hello World!!!!</h1> 
               </greet>`
 })
 export class AppComponent{ }
```

Content projection is very useful to insert shadow DOM in your components.
To insert HTML elements or other components in a component, you need to use content projection.

Comment: Thanks for you reply brother, I will try this concept.

Answer (score 1):

Within a component, you can use Content Projection to define a placeholder using the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag.

In your example, you can use the `<ng-content></ng-content>`-tag within the HTML of your `car-layout` component. It will then be replaced by arbitrary content you are nesting within your `car-layout` component. For example

```
<car-layout>
  <p>Any HTML content</p>
</car-layout>
```

will project `<p>Any HTML content</p>` into your `car-layout` component and replaces the `<ng-content></ng-content>`-tag. Instead of the predefined paragraph `p`, you can also project your own components into the `car-layout` component:

```
<car-layout>
  <steering [color]="'black'"></steering >
  <rear-view-mirror [size]= "'12'"></rear-view-mirror>
</car-layout>
```

If one selector to project your content is not enough, you can also define multiple slots with Targeted Projection.

For more detailed information, look e.g. [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/) or [here](https://medium.com/@IMM9O/angular-content-projection-the-complete-guide-45d3bc1692f2).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will read about it and implement this concept.